# Looking for an sql solution, without using Oracle analytic functions, to split up scheduled hours into different activities

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

I am looking for a solution in sql (without using any analytic functions) to fill in the gaps and slot in the Breaks and Lunch during the scheduled hours.

Note, there are two scheduled hours in the day with no activities in between. The second shift goes past midnight to the next day.

Also, the second scheduled hours have more hours scheduled hours than activities allocated to it.

In this case, a 'N/A' description will be added to it.

Below is the sql to create the source data.

```
SELECT 'Meetings',to_date('2010-01-01 7:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 9:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL  

SELECT 'Shift',to_date('2010-01-01 7:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 9:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Shift',to_date('2010-01-01 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-02 00:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Floor',to_date('2010-01-01 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 21:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Break',to_date('2010-01-01 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 16:10:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Lunch',to_date('2010-01-01 17:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 18:15:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Break',to_date('2010-01-01 20:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-01 20:10:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 'Close',to_date('2010-01-01 23:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('2010-01-02 00:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

The expected result is a follows:

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Meetings | 2010-01-0107:00:00 | 2010-01-0109:00:00 |
| Floor    | 2010-01-0115:00:00 | 2010-01-0116:00:00 |
| BREAK    | 2010-01-0116:00:00 | 2010-01-0116:10:00 |
| Floor    | 2010-01-0116:10:00 | 2010-01-0117:30:00 |
| MEAL     | 2010-01-0117:30:00 | 2010-01-0118:15:00 |
| Floor    | 2010-01-0118:15:00 | 2010-01-0120:00:00 |
| BREAK    | 2010-01-0120:00:00 | 2010-01-0120:10:00 |
| Floor    | 2010-01-0120:10:00 | 2010-01-0121:30:00 |
| N/A      | 2010-01-0121:30:00 | 2010-01-0123:30:00 |
| Close    | 2010-01-0123:30:00 | 2010-01-0200:30:00 |
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Step 1 - format your question so the code appears as code.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use standard SQL window functions?

Comment: Why "without using analytic functions"? Don't ever put such constraints in place without explaining WHY. One may wonder, if analytic functions can't be used, then what else should not be used? Understand that analytic functions have existed in Oracle since Version 8, released in 1998.

Comment: And, when you post the same question with additional restrictions, **say so** and include a pointer to your older thread, explaining **why** the answers you got there are not sufficient and what is new/different in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281665/splitting-time-range-based-on-activities-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting time range based on activities in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281665/splitting-time-range-based-on-activities-in-sql)

Comment: Thank you for your response mathguy.  The reason Oracle Analytic can not be used because i need to code this in Informatinca application.  Although there is a sql override function available, the company practice is not to use it and create all logic using informatic objects.  I disagree with this but its not my call.

Comment: As to why the previous solution did not work because when additional schedules were added and missing activities were introduced, the results were not complete.

Comment: If you can't use your own SQL in Informatica (and must use "Informatica objects"), not sure what you want.  I'll add the Informatica tag for you anyway.  Also, been a while since I've used Informatica, but even back then you could define your own transformations if needed (written in SQL or Java if required).